# How to return response to AWS API Gateway after several AWS Lambda invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, response, aws-api-gateway

Sorry if the title is not good enough, I am trying to achieve the following:

- API Gateway get Request 'A' and triggers Lambda Function B
- Lambda Function B writes to queue C
- Lambda Function D is listening on queue C (and gets triggered and process data and writes to queue E)
- Lambda Function F is listening on queue E (gets triggered and send response to the Request 'A'.

My question is how to maintain track of the request that was originated and how to properly respond to the API Gateway instance that was triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chaining of Lambda processing could be achieved by [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/index.html).

Step functions implement a state machine for synchronization among Lambda calls.

You can achieve the same with a synchronous Lambda invocation, but you have to pay double (waiting time of the caller and processing time of the callie).

The benefit of Step functions is, you don't pay for waiting.

Comment: Could I still use AWS Queues (SQS) in between the functions? thanks

Comment: The communication among Lambda is defined direct via Step Functions itself as input/output state. Of course, you can use any other AWS service in the Lambda, but not as a Step functions synchronization mechanism.

Comment: What do you mean by 'You can achieve the same with a synchronous Lambda invocation' ? How could I return response to the original request from API Gateway? taking into account that the lambdas were triggered by events of the SQS? thanks

Comment: Well, you can invoke another Lambda directly from a Lambda. So you can chain your processing as well, similar to function calls. The problem is, the call must blocking while you have to wait for the result in order to return it back to the gateway. So you pay for all the parallel invocations. With Step functions you pay only for one lambda at time.

Comment: Check out the introduction whether Step Functions match your needs or not: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html

Comment: I am not sure I could even do a chain of lambda calls and wait on them, because they would be triggered by events (new messages on SQS queue), like the example I posted on the question. I think the only solution from what i am aware now is using step functions like u mention. thanks

Comment: It really depends on your use case. Sometimes it's okay just to return "ok" and let the client to pull the result, or you can put the whole processing in one lambda. Api Gateway support even WebSockets now, maybe it would be an option for you as well, but it's architecture design and it's out of the scope of SO. If my answer helped, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot do that. After Lambda Function B writes to Queue C, it is done. Invocation of Lambda Function D is event-driven and not on-demand and you cannot wire up multiple individual processes in the original request A as it is done by that time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I though the variable context could maintain the status of the call chain or something like that

Comment: You can pull this off with Step Functions if you get rid of SQS and event-driven approach and if the state machine execution can complete within 5 minutes. But then you don't even need Step Function. Just use Lambda Function B to do everything.